# xml parser, in iPhone

Tags: iphone, parsing, date, nsxmlparser

Am getting date (10/02/2011) in xmlresponse how to get this value in to string using NSXmlParserDelegate. "/" blocks me and am not getting how to handle this..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Use NSDateFormatter to get date from NSString from any formats.

Comment: but "/" is the ending tag in xml response. And this splits the date into 3 strings... thats the problem na

Answer (score 0):

You have not been clear where this xml data is coming from, I couldnt turn anything up on how dates should be formatted in xml. The first thought is "you are doing it wrong" if you can try using a different separator for dates, parse them out of the stream before you give the data to NSXMLParser. I know which I would prefer.

Comment: If he asked question is wrong, If you know Please correct it. You are said that, " I know which I would prefer" . It is a forum for ask questions, If you can answer the question